# Imagick not working, returns no errors

Tags: php, wamp, imagick

So I am trying to resize an image from a form which is a .png, like so:

```
$logo = new Imagick($_FILES['icon']['tmp_name']);
$logo->resizeImage(256, 256, 0, 1);
```

When I `die` the `$_FILES['icon']['tmp_name']` it returns the .tmp file like so:

```
C:\wamp64\tmp\php7895.tmp
```

But when running the above code, it throws no errors, but just breaks the script, if I add a `die` after the code, it doesn't reach that part.

I have checked my error logs, which is empty, and my Imagick is enabled:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there anything else I could try or how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure, things are being written to the error log and you are looking in the right place? Have you tried to cause an error log by calling a not existing function, for example?

Comment: Yep. Using right error log as you can see here by the error I just caused: https://i.imgur.com/RwB0vAr.png

Comment: Try to read apache error log.

Comment: None are showing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong filtering. Try this:

```
$logo->resizeImage(320,240,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
```

[Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.resizeimage.php)